# Find the size of an android/iphone app from Android studio/Xcode?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio, compilation

Is there a way to find the size of an android or iphone app from Android Studio or Xcode during development? For example, for android I do not mean finding the size of the apk file in Windows explorer after compiling is finished, as I think that would be the size of the compressed package file and not really the size of the actual android program. Also, the size of the program shown on the App store would also be the size of the apk file wouldn't it? Or does it indicate actual program size?

Non-the-less, I would like to find this value while in development, from the Android Studio interface. Is there any way to find this information while compiling the program? Do any of the build messages indicate the final size of the android program? For example, in many embedded system development IDE's, after compilation it would show the size of the final hex file, which is the actual size of the program. I would like to know similar information for an android app from the IDE itself. Are there any compiler options that I need to enable in order to show me these things? My android program contains both java and native cpp code.

I would also like to know the corresponding information for iphone in Xcode.

Comment: Note you have a number of different questions. Some involving what the Play Store reports. Do you consider the run-time files of [ART](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/jit-compiler) part of size question?

Comment: @MorrisonChang no I don't need to consider Android Runtime

Comment: Given that there is documentation on [Reduce your app size](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size), I'm not sure what benefit you are seeking (as during development debug symbols increase app size).

Comment: @MorrisonChang That page says "The easiest way to gain immediate app size savings when publishing to Google Play is by uploading your app as an Android App Bundle, which is a new upload format that includes **all your app’s compiled code and resources**, but defers APK generation and signing to Google Play." Is there a way to find the size of this *compiled code and resources* when compiling the android program? If debug symbols increase the size I would like to know this only for the release version

Comment: [APK Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer) and [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool) are probably what you are looking for. See [Google IO 2019 Optimize App Size session](https://youtu.be/rEuwVWpYBOY?t=1062) for more details.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks I have a look at them. Do you have any ideas about corresponding tools for Xcode?